# Teradata stored procedure - run delete statements which are stored in another table in a specific order in a store procedure in teradata

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata, sql-delete

I have a table T1 which has columns like C1,C2,C3...
C1 contains delete statement
C2 contains an order in which delete should be executed - 1,2,3
(if c2 is 1 then that delete should be executed first and then second so on and so forth)
C3 contains Y or N
(if C3 is Y then execute else skip )

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| delete from x | 1 | Y |
| delete from Y | 2 | Y |
| delete from Z | 3 | N |
| delete from P | 4 | Y |

Delete should be performed in a sequence 1,2,4 (not 3 because it is 'N')

so table X should be deleted first then Y and then P.
after the delete , I also need to capture number of deleted rows in another table for each delete.

how to achieve this via a stored procedure in teradata ?

Comment: Open a cursor in the correct order and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE the individual deletes.

Comment: @dnoeth  you mean this ? -:
begin
declare curr cursor for sel * from T where C3='Y'   order by C2;
open curr ;
 del_loop : loop
fetch curr IN a,b,c;
execute immediate a;
end loop del_loop;
close curr;
end;

Comment: Yep, like this.